# Protect the global reference in javascript

Tags: javascript, scopes

The following javascript code, allows you to access the global object (window/worker).

```
(new function Outer(){
    console.log(this); /* The object */
    (function(){ // This function could be a 3rd Party function 
        console.log(this); /* window !!*/
    })();
});
```

Is there a way by which I can ensure that the inner this always gets a reference to Outer's context.

I know i can do

```
(new function Outer(){
    'use strict';
    console.log(this); /* The object */
    (function(){ // This function could be a 3rd Party function 
        console.log(this); /* undefined ? !!*/
    })();
});
```

but that results in `this` being undefined.

**Edit**

I know about `bind`, but what if the inner function is nested. for instance something like

```
(function(){

    (function(){
        (function(){
           console.log(this);// undefined
        })();

    })();

}).bind(this)();
```

**What i want is : Outer {}** and not a reference to the outer using a variable :-|

Comment: So you don't want `window`, but you also don't want `undefined`. Hate to break it to you, but those are the two defaults that will be used for functions that are invoked without any other indicator of the `this` value.

Comment: Thats why i asked, wondering if there exists a trick to not have either.. But i guess i will have to be satisfied with `undefined`

Comment: Nope, no trick. I'm not sure what the value would be if it wasn't either of those. ECMAScript 6 will have functions with a lexical `this`, but that's of little use today, and it's only for functions with the new syntax.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [function.call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
new function Outer(){
    'use strict';
    console.log(this); 
    (function(){ // This function could be a 3rd Party function 
        console.log(this);  //<-- Now it will it the one from the outer scope
    }).call(this);
}; // You don't need to invoke this explicitly here with () since you are invoking it already with new keyword so constructor invocation doesnt need ()
```

Or a best bet would be to cache the context outside and use it anywhere in the inner scope.

```
new function Outer(){
        'use strict';
        var self = this;
        console.log(this); 
        (function(){ // This function could be a 3rd Party function 
            console.log(self);  //<-- Now it will it the one from the outer scope
        })();
 };
```

Comment: What if the inner function is nested a few level in ?

Comment: I think you meant `.bind(this)()`, but +1 for doing the right thing.  (Also you could use `.call(this)` and have it work *way* back :-)

Comment: @AbhishekHingnikar The other solution is to store a reference to the outer `this` inside another variable, like `var that = this` and then use `that` to refer to the outer `this` variable. However, that requires you to edit the code of the inner function.

Comment: @SeanVieira yeah i meant call... :) Good catch

Comment: @SeanVieira or `call` & `apply` for that matter

Comment: @AbhishekHingnikar if you have too many of them, then use a cached context.

Comment: I know it was from the code in the question, but the final trailing `()` shouldn't be there since the `Outer` function is invoked with `new`. You can also get rid of the wrapping `()`.Just `new function Outer() {...};` is enough.

Comment: @PSL hmm i can't bind each of them and since the inner function can be 3rd party its a no-luck.

Comment: @BlueSkies yeap my bad... didn't notice that :D removed it

Comment: @AbhishekHingnikar What 3rd party plugin you are using? Does it have a context specification option or something? You cannot do it the traditional way otherwise just by binding it in the outer level

Comment: I was attempting to write a sandbox for other applications to run freely within mine with some restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a closure variable:

```
(new function Outer(){
    'use strict';
    console.log(this);
    var me = this;
    (function(){
        console.log(me);
    })();
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This trick simply stores the "outer" `this` inside a variable that you can access from inner functions (and inner-inner function and so on).

In some cases, this can be useful because you have access to both the inner `this` (if there is a context for it) and the outer `this`.

```
(new function Outer(){
    'use strict';
    console.log(this); /* The object */
    var _this = this;
    (function(){ // This function could be a 3rd Party function 
        console.log(_this); /* The outer object */
    })();
})();
```